# What is the benefit of base class variable holding derived class object?

Tags: oop, inheritance

I know that it is possible to base class variable holding derived class object. Like below....

```
class Animal
{
    public void printName()
    {
        System.out.println("Print your name");
    }
} 

public class Tiger extend Animal
{
    public void Print()
    {
        System.out.println("My Name");
    }
    public void static main(String args[])
    {
        Animal type1 = new Tiger();
        //with this new created type1 varibale. I can only access members of Animal class.
        type1.PrintName() // valid
        type1.Print() //In-valid
    }
}
```

So what is the usefulness of this? Still I don't see any benefit. Can someone explain me, may be I am missing something. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, where the variable is *initialized* from a child class variable, it isn't terribly useful.  The usefulness comes in two cases:

- When you have a function *parameter* with a base class type and you pass in a child class object as the actual argument.

  ```
  void CareForAnimal(Animal anm) {
      anm.Feed();
      anm.Sleep();
  }
  ```

  While it's technically possible to allow you to do things with formal parameters you can't do with regular variables, as a language designer it's a lot of complication to make them different for not a lot of benefit.
- When you have a base class variable initialized from the result of a method which is itself virtual:

  ```
  Animal Breed(Animal father, Animal mother) {
      Animal child = mother.mater(father);

      child.Bathe();
      child.Nurse(mother);

      return child;
  }
  ```

Now, you *don't* know right away which child class `child` is being initialized with.